# How do I enumerate all open files on a system in c#?

Tags: c#, filesystems, console-application

Trying to enumerate all open files on a Windows system in C#.  I cannot find a native way to do it, is there any other way other than using the NtQuerySystemInformation API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this was quite intentionally not included in the documented API.  Enumerating open files can never work reliably on a multi-tasking operating system, you cannot 'freeze' the operating system and prevent other processes from opening and closing files while you enumerate them.  The race condition is unsolvable.  The only documented way is to try to open a file with no sharing.

Yes, NtQuerySystemInformation is the back door.  Used by SysInternals' Handle utility.  And maintained by them since every new version of Windows requires an update to the utility.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do it by first enumerating all handles on the system, and then getting the filename for each handle that is a filehandle.

This is an old program of me that enumerates handles, find the ones that are a process-handle to a certain process and prints them. You'll need to change it from process-handles to file-handles.
http://nopaste.info/eb9917d719.html But it uses NtQuerySystemInformation.

This describes how to get the filename from a handle:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789(VS.85).aspx